# What happens if you put a piece of copper into a solution containing Al3+ ions?

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, ions

This is a question in my studies, and I am a little bit confused! I would think it happens nothing because copper is below aluminium in the reactivity series, right?

Comment: You think right.

Comment: As a side reaction, it may get slowly oxidized by oxygen and dissolve in acidic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right with copper does not react with aluminium ions.

But as a side reaction, copper may get slowly oxidized by oxygen and dissolve in mildly acidic solution of aluminium salt.

Such a thing may happen, if you decalcify copper heating spiral by vinegar and let it stay overnight.

$$\ce{ 2 Cu + 4 CH3COOH + O2 -> 2 (CH3COO)2Cu  + 2H2O  }$$

Something similar can happen in aluminium salt solutions as well, because of hydrolysis.

$$\begin{align}
\ce{ [Al(H2O)6]^3+ + H2O &<=> [Al(H2O)5(OH)]^2+ + H+}  \\
\ce{ 2 Cu  + O2 + 4 H+ &->  2 Cu^2+ + 2 H2O} \\
\ce{ 2 Cu  + O2 + 2 H2O &->  2 Cu(OH)2 v} \\
\ce{ 2 Cu  + O2 +  H2O + CO2 &->   Cu(OH)2\cdot CuCO3 v} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your first equation got me into chemistry more than two decades ago as a home experiment! Nostalgic. Copper is not supposed to dissolve in acetic acid, however a small amount H2O2 starts to dissolve it.

Comment: I started when the chemistry textbook for a basic school, belonging to my 2-year-older sister, got into my hands. I do not remember any more interesting textbook ever :-) .

Comment: Do you remember the name of the textbook? Was it in English?

Comment: No, it was Czech one. I hardly ever knew few English words. English language was rather not preferred in the communist school system :-). German was taught more often because of the communist Eastern Germany

Comment: Eastern Europe was a leader in electrochemistry and theoretical side of chemistry. No wonder your electrochemistry is quite good.

Comment: The Germany leader Dagmar Merkel is from Eastern Germany, doing  post doc studies in quantum physics/chemistry in Prague at prof. Zahradník, the leader in Quantum chemistry development, later the head of the Czech academy